# Regex capture groups (lookbehind?)

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I have a string, which can contain 10 or more characters ([0-9a-zA-Z]), e.g.:
abcdefghij12345

I want to catch following characters in groups:

- Group 1: Character position "1 and 2": ab
- Group 2: Character position "3 and 4": cd
- Group 3: Character position "5 - 10": efghij
- Group 4: Character position "6 - Last position of string": fghij12345

Group 1-3 works, but how can a get postion "6 - last postion of string" in Group 4?

What I already have?

```
r'^([0-9a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9a-zA-Z]{6})'
```

I expect to get all four groups with one Regex expression. How to expand my expression to get additionally group 4?

*Edit:*
Additionally following Regex is needed for a string of 72 and more characters

I want to catch following characters in groups:

- Group 1: Character position "1 and 2"
- Group 2: Character position "3 and 4"
- Group 3: Character position "5 and 6"
  ...
- Group 16: Character position "31 and 32"
- Group 17: Character position "33 - 40"
- Group 18: Character position "41 and 42"
- Group 19: Character position "33 - 40"
- Group 20: Character position "12 - Last position of string"

String (72 char): 294592522929354526532268626626426854242342362676256672666267626726672667

```
r'^([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{8})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{8})'
```

Comment: Are you sure you want these in one regex? The groups in the 72+ char string and those in your original question don't seem to overlap well. If you want two separate regexes, put the question about the second regex in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead:

```
^([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})(?=([\da-zA-Z]{6})).([\da-zA-Z].*)$
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `([\da-zA-Z]{2})` - first capture group, pos 1-2
- `([\da-zA-Z]{2})` - second capture group, pos 3-4
- `(?=([\da-zA-Z]{6}))` - positive lookahead, third capture, pos 5-10
- `.([\da-zA-Z].*)` - discard one character and capture the rest as forth capture, pos 6-end
- `$` - end of line anchor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qboqbp/1)

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to format it in a good way :(

Thanks. I like the solution, but e.g. does not work when I try to use it for following scenario:
String of 72 characters and I group the first 56 characters in the following way:

```
^([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{8})([\da-zA-Z]{2})([\da-zA-Z]{8})
```

Comment: Additionally I want to capture character 12 - End of string in a group. Any idea?

Comment: @Thomas As long as the original requirements in your question holds, the above regex _should_ work without changes.  Character 12 wasn't mentioned in the question, so, can you please update the question to mention _all_ requirements?

Comment: @Thomas What was wrong with the first regex? It worked well for me (and in the demo).

Comment: First Regex was fine. It is not my downvote. I am just searching for a solution for the second regex, which I added to the original description. I justbhoped I could easily adjust the regex you already posted here.

Comment: @Thomas _"First Regex was fine"_ - Ok, great. Usually, when a question is answered, people accept the answer and move on to ask a new question. Adding to an already answered question isn't so popular :-) I don't see how to combine the two regexes easily. It becomes a very complex regex and you'll need to check how many capture groups you've got afterwards etc. I think you should keep these two separate.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an index/position issue, why not just using classical slicing with a *tuple-comp* ?

```
S = "abcdefghij12345"

g1, g2, g3, g4 = (S[i:j] for i, j in [(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 10), (5, None)])
```

Output :

```
ab          # <- group1 
cd          # <- group2
efghij      # <- group3
fghij12345  # <- group4
```

Comment: It's also a matter of matching `[\da-zA-Z]` but perhaps that validation could be made as a pre-step?

Comment: Maybe! I removed my regex approach anyway. Thanks Ted ;)